# Understanding iptables in routing device

Tags: iptables

So, I have been configuring a Raspberry Pi to act as a VPN router with the help of stunnel, OpenVPN and many online articles (mainly the ones from [Jayden Chua](https://medium.com/@jayden.chua/convert-your-router-into-an-openvpn-stunnel-router-15418f9c8690)) and can succesfully create one but I don't fully understand the iptables part (described below) although I have read some online help about the subject.

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o wlan1 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan1 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
```

Can anyone please explain each line to me? I know it may be simple but honestly I can't figure out why this works =P

Many thanks in advance =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, we need to define IP forwarding. I am not going to explain very deeply (neither do I know so), but basically, under this context, what you need to know is it means the flow of packets from a host to another via this host.

I have to remark that the none of the `-A FORWARD ... -j ACCEPT` rules/commands is necessary unless you have `-P FORWARD DROP` or similar (i.e. drop any packet that is supposed to be forwarded). The rules don't make forwarding happen, but only to make exception when the default is not "ACCEPT". (You "enable" forwarding with sysctl.)

Now we can look at the rules:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -j ACCEPT
```

This means to allow packets that comes in from wlan0 to be forwarded (to other network via any interface on this host).

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan1 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
```

This means to allow packets that comes in from wlan1 to be forwarded to tun0. (Note that this is not needed for the packets to reach the address(es) of tun0 itself, as that does not count as "forwarding".)

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o wlan1 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
```

This means to allow packets that comes in from tun0 to be forwarded to wlan1, only if there is related or established connection, checking with the extension/module `state` (it was obsoleted with `conntrack`, which takes the switch `--ctstate` instead). Together with the former rule, essentially they mean to allow forwarding between tun0 and wlan1, as long as the connection is not initiated by a packet from tun0.

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
```

This basically mean packets that go out of tun0 would have its source address changed to tun0's. If this is not done, the next router would need to have return route for any response to reach the original source address. (i.e. to reach the original source address, this host should be the gateway). This is also know as NAT (overloading) / PAT. Think of it as making tun0 work like the WAN port/interface of a typical consumer-grade router.

Answer (score 0):

To understand this, you must understand the principles of routing. However, I cannot write a book within this answer, so I'll keep it short and simple.

`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE`

This rule basically takes the package, applies [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation), but after the decision how to route this package is made. This is why it is applied to `POSTROUTING`. Then it sends the package back into the tunnel called `tun0`. This is your VPN connection. It also applies masquerade, because the rule does not know the IP of the device. Without it, you'd need to use this command for every device connecting. So you could see this as some sort of wild card.

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -j ACCEPT 
iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan1 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
```

This line says to accept all traffic forwarded to the `wlan0` interface. I assume `wlan0` is used as the primary internet connection in this guide, so this is main route between the router and the VPN tunnel. This makes the Pi accept packages on this interface and gives [access to the internal network](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Security_Guide/s1-firewall-ipt-fwd.html). The second line here is basically just the way back for the package. From the pi, back into the tunnel.

`iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o wlan1 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT`

This line allows the traffic coming from the tunnel `tun0` going to the interface `wlan0`, but only if a connection was [established](https://askubuntu.com/questions/854354/difference-between-established-and-listening) previously.

In a nutshell, those rules allow packages coming from the VPN tunnel to flow into the rest of the private network and back.